# IIS not serving Scripts folder content over default ports 80 and 443

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, sni

So we have a stage server running Windows 2012 R2 server (It was upgraded from 2008 R2)
It's running a bunch of asp.net MVC sites.

We used to run SSL sites on different ports to allow different domains before SNI.
Now that we can use SNI with 2012 R2 we are moving the bindings from their old ports to port 443.

However now when we try to serve content up from the scripts folder over http on port 80 we get a 404 and over https on port 443, we get a sudden disconnect (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in Chrome)

Here's the kicker: Adding another binding to a random port lets the content get served. It's only the scripts folder, making a copy of it to a different name or serving the same content out of the content folder works too. This was reproducible on a newly created (from scratch) web site.

```
Folder   | http:80 | http:81 | https:443 | https:23457 
content  | works   | works   | works     | works
scripts  | (404)   | works   | (reset)   | works
scriptsx | works   | works   | works     | works
```

It feels like someone set something up somewhere deep in the bowels of IIS and then never told anyone else.

Turning on failed request tracing at the server has not shown any log entries.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Folder"? IIS does not have that term, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis If you actually mean sites, tools like Binding Diagnostics and SSL Diagnostics should reveal if you have some incorrect configuration, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html and https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi. A folder is a directory, plain and simple. So when you make an asp.net mvc application you get a bunch of them out the box: one of them is called Content, and another one is called Script. Those are the ones I am referring to in my question.

Comment: Items under the same site should behave consistently, but you might see into IIS log files to learn what kind of 404 you hit, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 After resolving that you might check if the reset issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this: https://forums.iis.net/t/1191833.aspx

Turned out we had qlikview server installed from a pilot phase long ago. It was not even enabled anymore. Uninstalling it restored normal functionality.

Seems to have happened to someone else recently too: https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Deployment/QlikView-blocks-Scripts-folder-for-asp-net-pages-on-same-server/m-p/113060

Answer (score 0):

We had a very similar problem when upgrading from Windows 2008 to 2012.

In the end I built a new 2012 server with a fresh install of IIS and this fixed the issue.

Have you been able to test on a fresh install of Windows?

p.s. I'd have left this as a comment but I haven't built the reputation to do so yet.

Comment: While a new installation would probably fix the problem, I'm one of those people with a particular acute affliction of needing to know the root causes of weird behavior. Excited to hear someone else had a similar problem. What avenues did you explore when you had this? How did you you migrate your web-sites to the new installation?

Comment: This was one of those time sensitive issues where I planned to go back to the old box and find out what caused the issue but never made the time.  I'd tried deleting and recreating the scripts folder, created a new site using the folder structure then ran out of patience and created a new server.